# Logo is not getting clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The logo of this website, http://nxgndigital.com/sawan/hmhospitality/ which is linked to the homepage is not getting clicked. This is one of our websites. 
I have checked for the problem using Firefox and found that it's actually due to the jQuery, the logo of the website is not clickable. The following piece of code in jQuery is showing up when I tried to analyze the error:

```
}, ga.error = function(a) {
        throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + a)
```

This code comes at line no 471.

I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue and make the logo clickable again. Help me please.

Eagerly looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: If you remove `target=_self` from anchor tag, what is it giving as result ?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from main.js line 139.

You are trying to select an element with jQuery and the expression "http://nxgndigital.com/sawan/hmhospitality/" which is not a valid jQuery expression.

And the `e.preventDefault();` on line 137 is preventing the link to do its basic action, so that's why the link is not working.

Removing the "Nice Self Scroll" block (from line 136 to line 140) should fix your issue, but you will have to find another solution to have a smooth scroll top.

Comment: Hi Finrod. Your suggestion worked. You were right. It was the problem with the main.js of the theme. Removing the Nice Scroll - Code (line no 136 - 140) fixed the issue like as you said. Thanks a lot for your help :) Appreciate it.